# Why does the OnlyOnCanceled continuation get called?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, continuations, cancellation

When calling `await RunAsync();` on the below code, I would expect the continuation with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyRanToCompletion` continuation to run, however the `OnlyOnCanceled` continuation gets called (yielding the debug output "Task canceled").

Why?

```
private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => DoWork())
            .ContinueWith(
                (t) =>
                {
                    if (t?.Exception != null)
                    {
                        throw t.Exception;
                    }
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
            ).ContinueWith(
                (t) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Task canceled.");
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled
            ).ContinueWith(
                (t) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Task completed.");
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void DoWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding your continuations wrong.

Instead of adding three continuations to the "main" task, you're adding a continuation to a continuation to a continuation. When the main tasks finishes without error, the `OnlyOnFaulted` continuation gets cancelled, which triggers the `OnlyOnCanceled` continuation you incorrectly wired to the `OnlyOnFaulted` continuation instead of the main task. And then the best part - this means that the second continuation finished correctly, and since you wired your last continuation on the second continuation, the final continuation runs as well, so the full output is "Task canceled. Task completed." :)

It's not obvious what you're expecting to be the correct output, though. Why are you using continuations in the first place? `await` handles that for you much more nicely than you can ever do manually. Mixing `await` and `ContinueWith` is rarely a good idea :) Are you trying to `await` the main task (failing when an exception is thrown)? Or one of the continuations? Or just the `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` continuation (that's what you're doing right now, and it's never going to work the way you expect it to work)? What if that continuation never gets a chance to run?